# Передача значений переменных SwiftUI

Tags: state, swiftui, viewmodel

Есть Процесс регистрации пользователя состоящий из 2х View и View
ViewModel:

```
class RViewViewModel: ObservableObject{
        @Published var  fio = ""
        @Published var  username = ""
        @Published var  email = ""
        @Published var  password = ""
        @Published var  height: Int?
    
    init(){}
    func register(){
        UsersAPI.register(register: Register(fio: fio, username: username, email: email, password: password,  height: height)){ data, error in
            self.userInfo = data
            print(data)
            print("Ошибка \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

Первый экран с выбором роста:

```
struct SelectHeigth: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: RegisterViewViewModel
    @State var selected: String
    
      var body: some View {
                  VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 6){
                      Text("Укажите Рост")
                          .font(.headline)
                      CustomPicker(selected: self.$selected)  //значение, которое должно передаваться
                          .padding(.top,-70)
                      Button(action: {
                          viewModel.height = Int(selected)!
                      }, label: {
                          ZStack(){NavigationLink(destination:SelectTarget()){
                              Text("Продолжить")
                                  .foregroundColor(.white)
                                  .frame(width:365, height: 45)
                              .cornerRadius(5.0)}
                          .padding([.leading,.trailing], 20)
                              Image("continius")
                                  .resizable()
                                  .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                                  .padding([.top,.bottom],5)
                                  .padding(.leading,300)
                                  .foregroundColor(.black)
                          }
                      }) .padding(.bottom,100)
                  }
      }
}
```

Второй экран, на котором вводится фио, никнейм, почта и пароль:

```
struct FillProfile: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: RegisterViewViewModel
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 20){
                Spacer()
                Text("Заполните профиль")
                    .font(.headline)
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 16){
                    TextField("Полное имя", text: self.$viewModel.fio)
                        .frame(width:365, height: 45)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .padding(.leading, 5)
                        .cornerRadius(5)
                    TextField("Никнейм", text: self.$viewModel.username)
                        .frame(width:365, height: 45)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .padding(.leading, 5)
                        .cornerRadius(5)
                    HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 10){
                        Image("email")
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 25, height: 25, alignment: .center)
                            .padding([.top,.bottom,.leading],10)
                        TextField("Эл. почта", text: self.$viewModel.email)
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                    }.padding([.top,.bottom], 2)
                        .padding(.leading, 5)
                        .cornerRadius(5)
                    HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 10){
                        Image("password")
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 25, height: 25, alignment: .center)
                            .padding([.top,.bottom,.leading],10)
                        SecureField("Пароль", text: self.$viewModel.password)
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                    }.padding([.top,.bottom], 2)
                        .padding(.leading, 5)
                        .cornerRadius(5)
                    Spacer()
                    VStack(alignment:.center, spacing:25){
                     
                        Button(action: {
                            viewModel.register(fio: viewModel.fio, username: viewModel.username, email: viewModel.email, password: viewModel.password, height: viewModel.height)
                        }, label: {
                            Text("Регистрация")
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .padding([.top,.bottom],10)
                                .frame(width:365, height: 45)
                                .cornerRadius(5.0)
                            
                        })
                    }
                }
                }.padding([.leading, .trailing], 27.5)
                   
            }
            
        }
    
}
```

При нажатии кнопки "Регистрация" на сервер передаются переменные второго экрана. Что я делаю неправильно?